# Famous Question badge on questions with negative scores?

Tags: discussion, badges

> The *Famous Question* badge is awarded for question with 10.000 views.

I've seen questions with negative scores to be used as a reference to golden *Famous Question* badges. Why isn't there an additional requirement to have positive score on that question?

Is the intention of this badge to indicate helpful and interesting question or just number of views?

Comment: What does the badge description say?

Comment: Yes, you are right! I should probably make the first question, main question.

Answer (score 6):

The full description of the badge is:

Question with 10,000 views. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

This should be enough to answer your questions.

> Is the intention of this badge to indicate helpful and interesting question or just number of views?

Just number of views.

> Why isn't there an additional requirement to have positive score on that question?

Because it only indicates number of views.

Comment: Maybe for a negatively scored question it should be renamed to _Infamous Question_.

Comment: [Great minds think alike @Fish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271838/famous-question-badge-awarded-for-a-question-with-negative-score?lq=1#comment882051_271842). (I did not see this question and its answers/comments before posting, just found it now)

Answer (score 4):

> Is the intention of this badge to indicate helpful and interesting question or just number of views?

The badge it just to appreciate the fact that *a lot* of people had the same question. If you want to ask "What positive behavior does the badge encourage?", I think it is because of the traffic it attracts to the site (the site is useful and people found it using that question).

> Why isn't there an additional requirement to have positive score on that question?

Because the badge isn't there for asking a good question. It is in no way a measure of a good question, we have other badges for that, like *Nice Question*, *Good Question* and *Great Question*.