# Famous Question badge awarded for a question with negative score

Tags: support, badges

I just noticed that [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2516310/amarjeet-singh) got a Famous Question badge for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276077/how-to-redirect-mobile-users-to-mobile-version-of-my-site).

However, the question has a negative score. How come the badge was awarded for what appears to be a "bad" question?

Comment: Famous question badge is awarded when question has 10,000 views. His question currently has been viewed 18,345 times.Vote count is not a criteria. You can find more info about badges and how/when they are awarded [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges).

Comment: Unrelated to this particular case, you can get "Informed" badge without having any other activity too, so it's possible.

Comment: @AndrewT. true, but generally speaking, badges should reward positive behavior. Negative score on a question means it wasn't so good, so getting a gold badge for bad question sounds off indeed. I play with the idea of starting a feature request to change the behavior, e.g. add "And question must have positive score" to those badges.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: While I kind of agree with that point, the question is still famous (for whatever reason) enough to have got so many views. We already have the Great question badge for a vote-based measure.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Post it! Post it!

Comment: @Nat eager to downvote? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: More the contrary, actually.

Comment: Just now found the dupe, when looking if a feature request exist already. Oops.

Answer (score 8):

As it stands now, the [Famous Question badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question) requires only one thing:

> Question with 10,000 views

And that is all. Score of the question is not relevant for the badge, being closed also does not have any effect on the badge. Only views, meaning many people saw it.

Fair or not fair, should be changed or not, is matter for a different discussion or feature request.

Comment: If you make a feature request, I will also support it. But maybe try some suggestion for a name change also along with it. I am just going literally based on the badge name - Even wrong-doers are famous in the outside world (but for wrong reasons).

Comment: @Harry Infamous Question? ;)

Comment: Nope, I think that's also incorrect. Let me think of something (and ping you here). Am thinking of something along the lines of "Celebrated" maybe - Famous and positive.

Comment: make the supporters two.

Comment: @SPA three, with [Nathan](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271838/famous-question-badge-awarded-for-a-question-with-negative-score/271842?noredirect=1#comment882039_271838). Hmm... tempting. :)